# angularjs table <td> binding with a same function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am now using AngularJS to create a table with `ng-repeat`. One column likes this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in A"><td>{{calNoMonth(x)}}</td></tr>
```

However, when I tested it, if I change any cell in this table, `calNoMonth` function will be called N (N is the number of rows in this table) times. How can I avoid this? It will be very slow if the table is quite large.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use one way binding like so:

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in A"><td>{{::calNoMonth(x)}}</td></tr>
```

This way the angular won't try to keep a watch on the what's inside `ng-repeat`

Comment: Hi Guranjan, Thanks for your reply. I do need a watch inside ng-repeat. calNoMonth will use another cell's value in this row to calculate and return the value for this <td> cell. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: @coder If you need the value to be updated then you would need to call the function. If there's too many rows, then maybe look into pagination?